# display file name in a single array in multer using nodejs

Tags: node.js, multer

here is a part of my code of multer using nodejs

```
const storageEngine = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, './Images')
        const Files = [file.originalname]
        console.log(Files)
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
})
```

the console log of the above code is this:

```
['image.png']
['image2.png']
['image3.png]
```

so i want all file names to be in one array to be posted in mysql in one go as i do not want to send multiple request to mysql as there are numerous amount of images.

so all i want is the file names to be present in one single array like this:

```
['image.png', 'image2.png', 'image3.png']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `destination` event that you use is invoked once per uploaded file, so you cannot use it to collect all file names.

Assuming you have an input field `<input type="file" multiple name="upload">`, you can instead use

```js
app.use(storageEngine.array("upload"))
.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.files.map(file => file.originalname));
  next();
});
```

Comment: after hours of work here i get the answer . THANK YOU.